# PDF Preview before File Upload MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, pdf

In my application, the user will have the ability to upload documents.

It looks like this:

[image: this]

Now underneath I want a file preview and for pictures it works. However, when I try to preview PDF it shows this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<img id="output" height="200" width="200" 
     accept="'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png,application/pdf'" />

<script>
  var loadFile = function (event) {
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  };
</script>
```

Is it because of the `<img>` tag? and it will only display images?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can't display pdf in image tag.

Comment: okay, that is what I figured.. is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html?rq=1).